# Is CCD vs CMOS sensor the deciding factor between two budget compact cameras?

Tags: sensor, camera-recommendation, travel, low-budget

I'm buying a compact digital camera for travel usage by a person not very good with computers. The purpose is to shoot pictures better than with a phone and nothing else, meaning that it should be cheap enough (less than $100) to not worry if it gets some sand on it or gets stolen. I managed to narrow the choice to two candidates: [Sony w810 vs Nikon L31](http://cameradecision.com/compare/Sony-Cyber-shot-DSC-W810-vs-Nikon-Coolpix-L31).

The main difference seems to be the sensor: CCD vs CMOS.

My questions:

- Which sensor would you recommend for this purpose?
- Which camera would you recommend?

Comment: "*better than with a phone*" does that person have a phone? If so, which one? Does it have a camera?

Comment: The phone has 3 MP camera, it's an old Samsung Galaxy

Answer (score 0):

I travel with a Panasonic DMC-ZS40. Has GPS that labels (or not) the date, time, country, city, landmark etc. Has a zoom that is awesome. Sorry, to report it is superseded by a model without GPS, otherwise a little improved. If my travel camera were lost, I would replace. You can still get the ZS40 from sources on the web. This model features both a rear LCD screen and an eyelevel LCD viewfinder that works in bright sunlight.

The CCD requires peripheral devices to process and time the signal, this takes lots more power than a CMOS which is more integrated. The battery life of a CCD is reduced compared to a CMOS.